# How to convert char "Q" to 3 bytes in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

i am creating data packet in byteArray i want to convert char ch= "Q" to 3 bytes please help how to solve this.

Comment: Which 3 bytes?  What algorithm are you trying to use? What have you tried?  Do you mean that you want a 3-byte array to contain only the letter Q?  Beginning or end?  Which endian?  Big or little?

Comment: char domainName = @"Q";
    NSData *d1 =[@"Q" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding]; i want to convert into bytes but byte length should be 3    packetOutput = [[DataOutputStream alloc]initWithData];
        [packetOutput writeChar:startOfFrame];

Comment: Will the letter always be Q, or might it be any Unicode character?

Comment: the letter always  Q

Answer (score 0):

```
char b[] = {0, 0, 'Q'};
NSData *d = [NSData dataWithBytes:b length:3];
```

You may need to swap the Q to a different position, depending on the precise byte order which is expected.